# Odd subroutine compilation errors in Perl script

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, subroutine

Two pieces of ASCII text (one L = long and one S = short) were read into @arrayOne and @arrayTwo, respectively, for comparison. The following subroutine &analyse gets two array references from the smart.pl code, but throws an error when checked via perl -c smart.pl. Unfortunately I can't figure out why:

```
68  sub analyse {
69      my $arraysize ; my $arrLref ; my $arrSref ; my $item_L ; my $item_S ; my $value ;
70
71      $arrSref = shift ; $arrLref = shift ;
72      $item_S = shift @{ $arrSref } ;
73      $item_L = shift @{ $arrLref } ;
74
75      $arraysize = $#{ $arrSref } ;
76      while ( $arraysize > 0 ) {
77          $value = ( $item_S cmp $item_L ) ;
78          given ( $value ) {
79              when ( -1 ) {
80                  push ( @mergedArray , $item_S ) ;
81                  $item_S = shift @{ $arrSref }
82              }
83              when ( 0 ) {
84                  push ( @mergedArray , $item_L ) ;
85                  $item_S = shift @{ $arrSref } ;
86                  $item_L = shift @{ $arrLref }
87              }
88              when ( 1 ) {
89                  push ( @mergedArray , $item_L ) ;
90                  $item_L = shift @{ $arrLref }
91              }
92              default { &die }
93          }
94      }
95  }
```

Compilation is aborted with the following statements:

```
    $ perl -c smart.pl 
    syntax error at smart.pl line 78, near ") {"
    syntax error at smart.pl line 83, near ") {"
    syntax error at smart.pl line 88, near ") {"
    Global symbol "$item_L" requires explicit package name at smart.pl line 89.
    Global symbol "$item_L" requires explicit package name at smart.pl line 90.
    Global symbol "$arrLref" requires explicit package name at smart.pl line 90.
    syntax error at smart.pl line 91, near "}"
    smart.pl had compilation errors.
```

Maybe someone else has a clue? Thx in advance –DrP-

Comment: You have `while ( $arraysize > 0 ) { ...`  Don't you need `$arraysize = $#{ $arrSref };` above the second to last `}`, so the loop terminates, or just `while ( $#{ $arrSref } ) { ...` and omit `$arraysize = $#{ $arrSref };` altogether?

Comment: Which version of perl your using?Give when statement is available only in perl 5.18.0...

Comment: can you post here the output of perl -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements), in order to use `given` and `when`, two conditions need to be met:

1. You need to `use feature "switch";`
2. You need Perl 5.10.1+

That should explain what you're seeing on lines 78, 83, and 88.

Regarding the warnings you're seeing on lines 89 and 90, these are tied to the use of `use strict;`, and an excellent explanation of these warnings can be found [here](http://perlmaven.com/global-symbol-requires-explicit-package-name).

Comment: or do `use 5.10.1;` (or higher) which will automatically enable features

Comment: Thx, but Perl v5.16.2 says "Use of Switch is deprecated." So I chose the given-when syntax. -DrP-

Comment: @DrParzival, 1) 5.16.2 does not say Switch is deprecated. Perl doesn't know anything about Switch. 2) `use feature 'switch'` is not `use Switch;`. As John Saxton said, the former provides given/when. Note that given/when is marked as experimental (and 5.18+ will warn you about this).